# Remove clicked <li> onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have this JavaScript code:

```
window.onload = init;

function init () {
    var button = document.getElementById("submitButton");
    button.onclick = addItem;
    var listItems = document.querySelectorAll("li");  //assigning the remove click event to all list items
    for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
        listItems[i].onclick = li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
    }
}

function addItem() {
    var textInput = document.getElementById("item");  //getting text input
    var text = textInput.value;   //getting value of text input element
    var ul = document.getElementById("ul");  //getting element <ul> to add element to
    var li = document.createElement("li");  //creating li element to add
    li.innerHTML = text;    //inserting text into newly created <li> element

    if (ul.childElementCount == 0) {  //using if/else statement to add items to top of list
        ul.appendChild(li);       // will add if count of ul children is 0 otherwise add before first item
    }
    else {
        ul.insertBefore(li, ul.firstChild);
    }
}

function remove(e) {
    var li = e.target;
    var listItems = document.querySelectorAll("li"); 
    var ul = document.getElementById("ul");
    li.parentNode.removeChild(li);        
}
```

and this HTML:

```
<body>
     <form>
         <label for="item">Add an item: </label>
          <input id="item" type="text" size="20"><br>
         <input id="submitButton" type="button" value="Add!">
     </form>
     <ul id="ul">
     </ul>
     <p>
         Click an item to remove it from the list.
    </p>  
</body>
```

What I want to do is remove the whichever `<li>` element the user clicks, but this doesn't seem to be working and I am unable to find an answer anywhere else online for this specific scenario.  Hoping someone can help me out here and show me what i am missing.

Comment: `listItems[i].onclick = function(e) {li.parentNode.removeChild(li)};`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

***UPDATE***

**Plain JS delegation**

Add the eventListener to the UL to delegate the click even on dynamically inserted LIs:

```
document.getElementById("ul").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  var tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.tagName.toUpperCase() == "LI") {
    tgt.parentNode.removeChild(tgt); // or tgt.remove();
  }
});
```

**jQuery delegation**

```
$(function() {
  $("#submitButton").on("click",function() {
    var text = $("#item").val();   //getting value of text input element
    var li = $('<li/>').text(text)
    $("#ul").prepend(li); 
  });
  $("#ul").on("click","li",function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

***Original answer***

Since you did not mention jQuery

```
var listItems = document.getElementsByTagName("li"); // or document.querySelectorAll("li"); 
for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
  listItems[i].onclick = function() {this.parentNode.removeChild(this);}
}
```

you may want to wrap that in

```
window.onload=function() { // or addEventListener
  // do stuff to the DOM here
}
```

Re-reading the question I think you also want to add that to the dynamic LIs

```
li.innerHTML = text;    //inserting text into newly created <li> element
li.onclick = function() {
  this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
   // or this.remove(); if supported
}
```

Here is the complete code as I expect you meant to code it

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/f4Ex8/)

```
window.onload=function() {
  var button = document.getElementById("submitButton");
  button.onclick = addItem;
}   

function addItem() {
  var textInput = document.getElementById("item");  //getting text input
  var text = textInput.value;   //getting value of text input element
  var ul = document.getElementById("ul");  //getting element <ul> to add element to
  var li = document.createElement("li");  //creating li element to add
  li.innerHTML = text;    //inserting text into newly created <li> element
  li.onclick = function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    // or this.remove(); if supported
  }
  if (ul.childElementCount == 0) {  //using if/else statement to add items to top of list
    ul.appendChild(li); // will add if count of ul children is 0 otherwise add before first item
  }
  else {
    ul.insertBefore(li, ul.firstChild);
  }
}
```

In case you want to use jQuery, the whole thing gets somewhat simpler

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/p8FYt/)

```
$(function() {
    $("#submitButton").on("click",function() {
        var text = $("#item").val();   //getting value of text input element
        var li = $('<li/>')
          .text(text)
          .on("click",function() { $(this).remove()});
        $("#ul").prepend(li); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the non jquery answer, i put this into my init function in place of what i had and it didnt work, although i think i see why it would work, but maybe something in the addItem function is messing it up, i have added it to the code above.  Am i missing something?

Comment: See update. You have a function init that I do not see executed. If you use window.onload it should work better

Comment: @mplungjan ;) just saw your update, will remove my comment then, as it's no longer needed. ;)

Comment: just forgot that part of the code, good eyes everyone! the last edit of this answer got me exactly what i needed with minimal code, thank you for the answers!

Comment: You are welcome. For completeness sake I added a jQuery version

Comment: Why not `this.remove()`?

Comment: @programmer5000 - that works in Chrome. Does it work in IE too?

Comment: [Caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=childnode-remove). You could also do `element.outerHTML = "";`, which has [much better browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=childnode-remove). Even better than `this.parentNode.removeChild(this);`

Comment: So I was correct. It is not supported by IE. Also outerHTML is not standard JS. Mine is DOM CORE 2

Comment: And even jQuery uses removeChild in its code https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js

Answer (score 5):

**I know you already received an answer, but back to your original remove function. You have the following:**

```
function remove(e) {
    var li = e.target;
    var listItems = document.querySelectorAll("li"); 
    var ul = document.getElementById("ul");
    li.parentNode.removeChild(li);        
}
```

**Change it to this and you should get what you were trying to achieve:**

```
function remove(e)
{
   var li = e.target;
   var ol = li.parentElement;
   ol.removeChild( li);
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, appreciate all the insight i can get.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest simplifying things a little:

```
Object.prototype.remove = function(){
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};

var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');

for (var i = 0, len = lis.length; i < len; i++) {
    lis[i].addEventListener('click', remove, false);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/SkzGV/).

Of course, having done the above, I'd then have to go further (possibly because I like jQuery too much) and also:

```
Object.prototype.on = function (evt, fn) {
    var self = this.length ? this : [this];
    for (var i = 0, len = self.length; i < len; i++){
        self[i].addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
    }
};
Object.prototype.remove = function(){
    var self = this.length ? this : [this];
    for (var i = 0, len = self.length; i < len; i++){
        self[i].parentNode.removeChild(self[i]);
    }
};

document.querySelectorAll('li').on('click', remove);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/SkzGV/1/).

Comment: It would be better if you extend the prototype of `HTMLLIElement` IMHO!

Comment: Possibly, yes; but then that's limiting the use-case to *only* the `HTMLLIElement`s.

Comment: I suggest HTMLLIElement *in this case* obviously, anyway it would be better to extend HTMLElement prototype, or you could do something like {}.remove() wich would throw an exception

Comment: you are now reinventing jQuery. I would really use jQuery instead of re-inventing `.on`

Comment: @mplungjan is it better to import 15kb of script to use `.on()` than writing your own function? lol

Comment: In my opinion yes. Once you imported it, the whole thing will be simpler to write

Comment: @mplungjan: it depends on what you're wanting to do; if this is *all* that's required I'd personally avoid importing jQuery (or any other library), but if the use-case justified it then yes, using jQuery would probably simplify things.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to write function in javascript, you can use immediately invoked anonymous function like below...

```
<elem onclick="(function(_this){_this.parentNode.removeChild(_this);})(this);"
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly:

```
$("li").on("click", function() {
  $(this).remove()
});
```

Comment: I don't see a jquery tag?!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is more obvious than it could seem, you forgot to add `init()` in your script, is normal that the click event aren't triggered, they're not set on the element!

**EDIT**:

Your code has some logical errors. If you don't add an onclick function for all those created elements you will not be able to remove the clicked element. This is because the function `init()` is called one time at the load of the page!

```
function init() {
    var button = document.getElementById("submitButton");
    button.onclick = function() {addItem()};
}

function addItem() {
    var textInput = document.getElementById("item"); //getting text input
    var text = textInput.value; //getting value of text input element
    var ul = document.getElementById("ul"); //getting element <ul> to add element to
    var li = document.createElement("li"); //creating li element to add
    li.innerHTML = text; //inserting text into newly created <li> element
    li.onclick = function() {this.parentNode.removeChild(this);}

    if (ul.childElementCount == 0) { //using if/else statement to add items to top of list
        ul.appendChild(li); // will add if count of ul children is 0 otherwise add before first item
    } else {
        ul.insertBefore(li, ul.firstChild);
    }
}
init();
```

Comment: there is an init function there, not sure what you are referring to

Comment: Yes, it is defined, but it is not called inside the script

Comment: I was already editing the answer before you edited yours, anyway you answered exactly as me(even if you read the comment in the OP question)

Comment: It would still fail. You need to call init after the DOM is ready, and your comment used li....(li) - and my initial version was a minute before your comment ;)

Comment: Yes, it would fail, I tried it in JSFiddle selecting the option "no wrap - in body", but this is something that the OP didn't requested, so IMO is superfluous in this case