# how to blast ballons on click or touch in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm rendering balloons on-screen 20 times, from an array of images, and I want em to blast on-click.

I have really no idea how to do that.

I have gone through the jquery method ".hide" with click event but that didn't happen.

I am sharing a plunker.

Thank you in advance!

```
my plunker:-
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/P27tZS4tBt18Kw2fOPZv?p=preview

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '.snow',`

Answer (score 0):

From what I read of your question you are just looking for a way to remove elements that have been added. Try something like this though you can replace the click button to create button feature with your timer:

```
<button onclick="createButton()">Try it</button>

<script>
var btnCount = 0;

var createButton = function(){
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.innerHTML = 'balloon';
  button.setAttribute("id", "newbtn" + btnCount);
var btnNumber = 'newbtn'+btnCount;
  button.onclick = function(){
document.getElementById(btnNumber).style.display = 'none';
};
  document.body.appendChild(button);
  btnCount++;
};
</script>
```

Comment: see this link.this is nothing but falling ballon effect and i want to blast ballons on touching on it....https://plnkr.co/edit/P27tZS4tBt18Kw2fOPZv?p=preview

Comment: See this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012157/remove-clicked-li-onclick     and this fiddle    http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/f4Ex8/