# javascript/html: Remove element by ID on button click

Tags: javascript

In short, what I want to do is make it so when I click a button in my HTML document, I want that button to subsequentely be removed by it's ID, using javascript if possible. I've been searching for a solution with no success, can anyone help me out here?

Comment: share your code

Comment: use onclick attribute, create function to handle click, refer to clicked element by "this" key word,... turn back and show us what you get

Comment: I have none as of now - all I'd like is a solution to this one minor problem. I don't believe that sharing my code will change anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove clicked <li> onclick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012157/remove-clicked-li-onclick)

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML:

`<button onclick="deleteSelf(this)">Click me</button>`

In your JavaScript:

```
function deleteSelf(button) {
    button.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

https://jsfiddle.net/00p4oLfy/

```js
document.getElementById('test').remove();
```

```html
<p id="test">This is a test</p>
<p id="test2">This is another test</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Html

```
<div>
   <button id="ClickMe">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

### Javascript

```
document.getElementById('ClickMe').remove();
```